# Proper class of nested rank into rank embeddings

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

I propose the following large cardinal axiom:

There exists a proper class of cardinals $\lambda$, such that for each $\lambda$, there exists a rank-into-rank embedding $j: V_\lambda \rightarrow V_\lambda$.

> **Question.** Is the above consistent with ZFC? If so, is it
> equivalent to any of the rank into rank axioms stronger than I3?

**Motivation.** If you had a property like the above, then maybe one could try "stitching together" the embeddings to get a non-trivial elementary embedding from $V \to V$, which is inconsistent with ZFC. But I don't see if this is guaranteed to happen or not.

Comment: One issue re: building an embedding $V\rightarrow V$ out of smaller elementary embeddings via some limit process is that even if we do get such an embedding, it might be the identity. For example, it is consistent **as far as we know so far** that there is a sequence $\langle j_\eta, \lambda_\eta\rangle_{\eta\in \mathsf{Ord}}$ such that $(i)$ $\eta<\alpha\implies \lambda_\eta<\lambda_\alpha$, $(ii)$ $j_\eta$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding $V_{\lambda_\eta}\rightarrow V_{\lambda_\eta}$, but $(iii)$ $\forall\alpha\exists\beta\forall\gamma>\beta(j_\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha)$ (limit-triviality).

Comment: The point is that while each of the $j_\eta$s are individually nontrivial, if we try to paste them together (at least, in the most obvious way) we just get the identity map on $V$. In order to push back against the Kunen inconsistency you'll need your rank-into-rank embeddings to "cohere" somehow, which (even before hitting a contradiction) will result in principles a **lot** stronger than a proper class of $\mathsf{I3}$s (which is what you've proposed).

Comment: The consistency follows from $I_2(V_\lambda)$, which implies $V_\lambda$ satisfies your principle.

Comment: See Laver's "Implications between strong large cardinal axioms."